# Does this sentence 「彼女が美しくなりましたね。」 need 「に」?

Tags: particle-に, adjectives, i-adjectives

Does this sentence:

> 「彼女が美しく [...] なりましたね。」

need 「に」 in the marked spot? And why? Can it be used both ways?

I tried searching for the 「に」 usage but it seems to be the most elusive particle as it's used in literally hundreds of different contexts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this sentence does not need に.

However, に does appear in a similar construction: When you want to use なる "to become" with adjectives, you use the 連用形 *ren'yōkei*, which is formed as follows,

1. for *na*-adjectives add に
2. for *i*-adjectives, delete い and add く

So

> 1. 彼女がきれい**に**なりましたね。
> 2. 彼女が美し**く**なりましたね。

Comment: But what is the specific rule that determines why I shouldn't put "ni" in the original sentence, but should in the example sentence you provided?

Comment: きれい is a *na*-adjective. 美しい is an *i*-adjective. The *ren'yōkei* of 美しい, which is 美しく doesn't take に as a particle. 美しくに is ungrammatical (and so is きれいなりました without the に).

Comment: Ah, now that makes sense! Thank you for clarifying that!

Comment: It's better you think of *i*-adjectives and *na*-adjectives as completely different parts-of-speech. (I only mentioned them both in the same answer, because I thought that's why you thought there might be a に there.)